# Angular to-do-list does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create to-do list.
Here is my html file. I faced a problem: the list of tasks is not displayed on the screen. Where is my mistake ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <div>
        <h1>Добавь заданий !</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="" ng-model='tempInput'>
            <button>Add</button>
        </form>
        <div>
            <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='task is tasksArray'>{{task}}</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my module & controller js file

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.tempInput = 'тестовое задане';
    $scope.tasksArray = ['this task', 'second task'];
});
```

ng-repeat doesn't work. why ?

Comment: This seems to be a simple typo.  `is` !== `in`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is **`task in tasksArray`** not **`task is tasksArray`**

```
  <li ng-repeat='task in tasksArray'>{{task}}</li>
  </ul>
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.tempInput = 'тестовое задане';
    $scope.tasksArray = ['this task', 'second task'];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <div>
        <h1>Добавь заданий !</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="" ng-model='tempInput'>
            <button>Add</button>
        </form>
        <div>
            <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='task in tasksArray'>{{task}}</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```